# What does「ゝ」mean?

Tags: meaning, classical-japanese, symbols

Now, I've been at least trying to read 竹取物語, and in the second sentence of my version it shows a odd symbol that I've yet to see.

```
野山にまじりて、竹を取りつゝ、萬づの事に使ひけり。
```

The symbol in question is the 「ゝ」 what does it mean? And what happens to the sentences translation as a result of it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration_mark#Kana

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ゝ is used to indicate previous hiragana is repeated.  In your example, you can regard the sentence to be exactly the same as below.

> 野山にまじりて、竹を取りつつ、萬づの事に使ひけり。

Comment: Cool, thx mate! :D