# What are these symbols?

Tags: symbols

1. ゐ and ゑ. Looks like an odd looking hiragana, but i never seen it before in the hiragana list.
2. ゝandゞ. What does it mean, and why there is a dakuten in the second one.
3. ヶ. It looks like ケ. Maybe it is ケ. I only know that it is readed か or が. Example: 藤ヶ谷 (ふじがや).

― 檜原 クリスチャン

Answer (score 3):

In modern あいうえお, the column of わ is わいうえを, but it used to be わゐうゑを. The pronunciation of these were more like "we" and "way" as opposed to the normal  い and え sound. I didn't know this myself, but apparently these old forms have disappeared as recent as 1946.

ゝ is a short-hand that means "repeating the previous letter", such as 学問のすゝめ (学問のすすめ). As you probably know, dakuten is composable decoration of a letter, and it can also decorate ゝ.

ヶ is an interesting one. I think its origin is at least in part katakana ケ, but I can't think of other katakanas that do this. Aside from the usage in 藤ヶ谷, which means 藤の丘, you also use ヶ to count objects, like 10ヶ.

Comment: For the last, we have some existing questions that explain where it came from: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/347/1478

Comment: And [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42118/what-does-%E3%82%9D-mean?rq=1) for the repeater character. It's kind of like a hiragana version of the repeater kanji 々 (for example, 時々＝時時＝ときどき).

Comment: `it used to be わゐうゑを` See https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%84%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%84 - う had its own *kana*.